# Simple tar extraction failing with file not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

I have a tarball called playground.tar with the following file:

test.txt

When I extract everything there is no problem but when I try and extract a single file it throws the following error when I run this command:

```
 tar xf playground.tar test.txt
```

> tar: test.txt: Not found in archive

> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

What gives I have also tried it with the path enclosed in quotes. The file definitely exists.

EDIT

The tarball was created with this command:

tar cf playground.tar playground

Comment: Update the question with the exact command you have used to create the archive.

Comment: It probably doesn't have `test.txt` exactly stored as that. It might be `./test.txt` or `some/path/to/test.txt`

Comment: So you want to extract `playground/test.txt` not `test.txt`

Comment: You can also use the TAB completion into the interactive shell. Type `tar xf playground.tar <TAB>` and it's like being into the directory tree. You can select the file you want.

Comment: Yea I figured it out the name of the tarball has to be in the relative path even though this is not done in the linux command line book I am following. Figures, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the whole path:

```
tar -xf playground.tar playground/test.txt
```

You can use `tar --list` or `tar -t` to list the contents of an archive to see what's in there:

```
$ tar -tf playground.tar
playground/
playground/text.txt
```

Here's a complete log of what I did to reproduce your issue:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)                              # Go to a new empty directory
$ mkdir playground
$ touch playground/test.txt                    # Make the file we will tar

$ tar cf playground.tar playground             # Make the tar
$ tar -tf playground.tar                       # List the contents of a tar
playground/
playground/test.txt                            # There's our file! It has a full path

$ rm -r playground                             # Let's delete the source so we can test extraction
$ tar -xf playground.tar playground/test.txt   # Extract that file
$ find .                                       # Check if the file is now there
.
./playground.tar
./playground
./playground/text.txt                          # Here it is!
```

---

Alternatively, you didn't need to pack the whole directory.  This would have also worked.  I also added `test2.txt` to show the whole directory isn't unpacked.

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)                 # New directory
$ touch test.txt test2.txt        # Let's make a few files
$ tar -cf playground.tar *.txt    # Pack everything
$ tar -tf playground.tar          # What's in the archive?
test2.txt
test.txt                          # Look: No directory!
$ rm *.txt                        # Clear the source files to test unpacking
$ tar -xf playground.tar test.txt # Unpack one file (no directory name)
$ find .
.
./test.txt
./playground.tar                  # There it is!
```

Answer (score 0):

The tarball name must be included in the file paths:

> tar xf playground.tar **playground**/test.txt